# UIButton as UINavigationItem titleView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to place a `UIButton` as the `titleView` for my `UINavigationItem`. This is my code but it doesn't work. The title is completely blank.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let titleButton = UIButton()
    titleButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 16)
    titleButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    titleButton.titleLabel?.text = "My Custom Title"
    titleButton.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the missing title.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Debug and check if it has an actual frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the title of the button you shouldn't be directly setting the text of the label, you should be configuring the button to set the title for a particular state using `func setTitle(_ title: String?, forState state: UIControlState)`.

Generally you set the title for `.Normal` and that will then apply to all states (as the default).

Comment: Thanks! What a rookie mistake. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Storyboards, you can drag a `UIButton` to the titleView. If Interface Builder doesn't let you do it, it's because you need to drag first a `UINavigationItem` to the navigation bar, so you can then drag views inside, like your `UIButton`.

Comment: Oh snap! I didn't know that was even possible. I'm going to accept the other answer as it directly answers what was wrong with the code in the question. However, I am going to go this route because it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @Fenda! Interface Builder is getting more and more powerful time to time, but in silence ;)